# Sqlite INSERT OR REPLACE is incrementing rowid

Tags: sqlite

I am using the `INSERT OR REPLACE` syntax to either insert or update a row that may exist based on a unique column constraint within the table.

The table structure is

```
| Name | Age | CustomerId (unique) |
```

When I print out the table the first time, I get something like

```
| Name | Age | CustomerId | rowid |
|"Bob" | 22  | 5          | 1     |
```

Then I run `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO MyTable(Name, Age, CustomerId) VALUES ("Bob", 23, 5);"`

Without fail, this will increment the `rowid` column each time it is run. So now the result is

```
| Name | Age | CustomerId | rowid |
|"Bob" | 23  | 5          | 2     |
```

How do I prevent rowid from incrementing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `INSERT OR REPLACE` works.
If a violation of a unique index/constraint occurs then the existing row is deleted and the new row is inserted, so a new `rowid` is assigned for the new row.

If you don't want this to happen you must use [`UPSERT`](https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

```
insert into tablename(Name, Age, CustomerId) values ('Bob', 23, 5)
on conflict(CustomerId) do update 
set Name = excluded.Name,
    Age = excluded.Age;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5QtwUagGVwroPKqSPMS56h/1).